# Is a question about Japanese dyslexia appropriate for the main site?

Tags: discussion

On one hand, most questions are about the mechanics and usage of Japanese.  他方, dyslexia is a disorder directly related to languages, and I'd like to ask something about its existence within the Japanese language.

Off-topic or on?  Vote below and comment with your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the question.

A question about if people with dyslexia can fare in Japan / if they're able to function as a member of society seems like it would be off-topic.

A question about, say, how to write sentences in Japanese to make it easier people with dyslexia to read seems like it would be more on-topic (though I'm not sure if that's subjective or not -- depends on whether there is research for it available).

Answer (score 1):

Provided it was suitably scoped, I can imagine an on-topic question about how dyslexia affects the reading/writing/learning of Japanese.

In some cases it could tip over into more of a cultural question, and in others might go over into territory better suited for another SE site (maybe Cognitive Science? Linguistics?), especially if you start getting into comparisons with other languages.